# getLastRowNum not returning correct number of rows

Tags: java, excel, row

I am having a small conundrum in using the getLastRowNum(). I am trying to get the number of rows with data from an Excel sheet. Supposing I have 3 rows, it should return in a print out statement stating 3 rows. My issue now is no matter how many rows I populate, it is returning me a certain fixed number. The following is excerpt of the code:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Test Data\\Login.xlsx"); 
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheet("Login");
System.out.println("No. of rows : " + sheet.getLastRowNum());
```

My Excel Sheet consist of the following

[image]

From the attached image, I should be getting row count of 4, but I am getting 6 instead.

Any advice is deeply appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Speaking about attached file, it should return row number of 3 because of the [XSSFSheet.getLastRowNum()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.html#getLastRowNum()) is zero-based. But if your receive a number of 6, it seems you have 3 additional blank rows in your sheet.

If you just open existing file and it contains blank rows, here is [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17945593/5708266) how to clean it. But if you fill the table by yourself, it seems you need to check you code for places where this empty line could be created.

Comment: Hi @Konstantin, thank you for your feedback. My mistake, it should return 3. With regards to the additional blank rows, may I have your advice on how to eliminate the blank rows, and to ensure that in the future, regardless of how many rows I add, it will give me the correct row count ? Thank you again

Comment: @lamCM Select rows 5-7 in Excel, delete them, and save the workbook again. However, your code will still be susceptible to such issues, so it's better to not rely on `getLastRowNum()`. Iterate the rows and check if they have non-blank data. You could iterate backwards from `getLastRowNum()` until you find a non-blank row, if you just want to find the last value-row, but you may still have blank/missing rows in-between other rows, so it all depends on what you need.

Comment: Another way to get a rows count is to iterate from the end until we get first non-blank row. And if the index of this row would be X, then return X + 1 (don't forget, X is zero based)

Comment: @Konstantin, followed your advise and it works well ! Thanks a lot !! Really appreciate your effort !

Answer (score 3):

it should return 3,
Check blank rows in your excel file and remove them

- click Find & Select
- click Go To Special
- Select Blanks and click OK
- Delete Sheet Rows

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, just delete all rows below the last row of your sheet(i.e. 4) and save. This is the quick fix.