# Unable to delete particular rows and empty string rows in xlsx spreadsheet using Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have this spreadsheet

[image]

I would like to iterate all the rows containing "USED" keywords and empty strings (spaces) , save all row numbers that match those criteria to an ArrayList , then loop my spreadsheet and remove all the row numbers listed in my ArrayList.

I tried and modified some solutions from Stackoverflow (one of them from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17251854/unable-to-delete-the-empty-rows-excel-file-using-apache-poi)) . My codes look like this

```js
 // Remove "USED" and empty string from spreadsheet
    private static void cleanUpSheet(String sheetName, String pathToExcel) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {

        FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(pathToExcel);
        Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(fileInput);

        List<Integer> toRemove = new ArrayList<>();

        int index = workbook.getSheetIndex(sheetName);
        if (index == -1)
            System.out.println("No sheet Found");
        else {
            System.out.println("Index " + index);
            Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(index);
            Iterator<Row> rowItr = sheet.iterator();
            DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
            System.out.println("Total ROW " + sheet.getLastRowNum());
            while (rowItr.hasNext()) {
                Row row = rowItr.next();
                if (containsValue(row, row.getFirstCellNum(), row.getLastCellNum())) {
                    //Row contains value
                    System.out.println("Value Cell 0 " + formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(0)));
                    if (formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(0)).equals("USED")) {
                        System.out.println("Value cell 0 should contain USED " + formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(0)));
                        toRemove.add(row.getRowNum());
                        System.out.println("What I am removing "+ row.getCell(4).getRichStringCellValue());
                    }
                    continue;
                } else {
                    //Row does not contain value
                    System.out.println("Empty row " + formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(0)));
                    toRemove.add(row.getRowNum());
                    System.out.println("What I am removing "+ row.getCell(4).getRichStringCellValue());
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0 ; i<toRemove.size() ; i++) {
                System.out.println("To Remove " + toRemove.get(i));
                removeRow(pathToExcel,toRemove.get(i),false,sheet);
            }

            System.out.println("New Total Row " + sheet.getLastRowNum());
        }

        fileInput.close();

        FileOutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream(new File(pathToExcel));
        workbook.write(outFile);
        outFile.close();
    }
```

```js
    private static void removeRow(String pathToExcel, int rowToBeRemoved, boolean removeIndexOneOnly, Sheet sheet) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {

        if (removeIndexOneOnly == true) rowToBeRemoved = 1;

        int lastRowNum = sheet.getLastRowNum();
        Row row = sheet.getRow(rowToBeRemoved);
        if (row != null && rowToBeRemoved != lastRowNum) {
            //System.out.println(row.getCell(3).getRichStringCellValue()); //For Testing
            //System.out.println(row.getCell(4).getRichStringCellValue()); //For Testing
            System.out.println("row to be removed " + rowToBeRemoved);
            System.out.println("last row " + lastRowNum);

            sheet.removeRow(row);
            sheet.shiftRows(rowToBeRemoved + 1, lastRowNum, -1);
        }

        if (rowToBeRemoved == lastRowNum) {
            System.out.println("Very Last Row");
            Row removingRow = sheet.getRow(rowToBeRemoved);
            if (removingRow != null) {
                sheet.removeRow(removingRow);
            }
        }


    }
```

The result looks like this

[image]

When I run in debug mode , I can see that my `List<Integer> toRemove` does list the correct row numbers I want to remove (i.e. containing "USED" and empty spaces). So far so good.

But when I execute this part of codes

```js
    for (int i = 0 ; i<toRemove.size() ; i++) {
                System.out.println("To Remove " + toRemove.get(i));
                removeRow(pathToExcel,toRemove.get(i),false,sheet);
            }
```

It just doesn't remove all rows listed in `List<Integer> toRemove`.

I am using POI 3.17.

I am wondering where could I do wrongly.

Thanks.

Comment: Your logic is wrong. Having your shown sheet, the `List<Integer> toRemove` will be `{1,2,3,4,5,21,22,23,24}` Now you are iterating this top down and do removing the rows. First row indes 1 gets removed. OK. But after that removing, former row index 2 is row index 1 now, former row index 3 is row index 2 now and so on. So next removing removes former row index 3 and not really former row index 2. The former row index 2 stays present. You can see this in your result as two of the "USED" rows stay present and instead two of the not "USED" rows gets removed.

Comment: And after the first 5 removes there is not even row index 21 anymore since this is row index 16 now. So the former rows 21,22,23,24 stay present as rows 16,17,18,19 now. If it comes to the requirement to remove elements from lists then do it always bottom up, never top down. So this behavior can be avoided.

Comment: Thanks Axel for the pointer :)